# How to move my saved logins and passwords from Google Chrome to Microsoft Edge?

Tags: password-management, microsoft-edge

Although, the option to import bookmarks and "other info" exists in Microsoft Edge settings, in practice when you select it, Edge doesn't import saved passwords from Chrome.

Checked this on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update `1709` and April Update `1804`.

Is there a way to import all of the saved passwords to Edge so I can move browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a very simple program which can import a CSV file with the passwords into Microsoft Edge (and Internet Explorer).

You can download it [on the releases page](https://github.com/gmanny/EdgePasswordImport/releases) of my repo, and check the source code [in the repo itself](https://github.com/gmanny/EdgePasswordImport), as it is only couple screens worth of code, you can easily check what it does.

To use the program, first **export Chrome passwords into a CSV file**.

1. To do this, you may first need to enable the export feature by going to chrome://flags/, entering `Export` into the search and flipping the "Password export" flag from "Default" to "Enabled". [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sZoN.png)
2. Then go to chrome://settings/passwords and click three dots beside **Saved Passwords** heading there, choose Export and select where to store the file. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mvFL.png)
3. Once that's done, run the `EdgePasswordImport.exe` file (you *should not* run it as Administrator), choose the `Chrome Passwords.csv` file in the Open dialog that pops up and your passwords should be imported into Edge.